# ¿Cómo ejecuto una función PHP desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo la necesidad de ejecutar una función PHP llamándola desde un archivo JavaScript cuando se hace clic en un botón. La función PHP, que quiero ejecutar, es parte de un plugin de WordPress y la llamo con fetch desde un archivo JavaScript que incrusté en la página.

Lo que busco, de ser posible, es que la función PHP simplemente se ejecute solo con llamarla, tomando los datos que necesite desde los demás archivos del plugin como si hubiese sido llamada desde el propio plugin, sin tener que pasarlos manualmente. Busco hacerlo de esta forma, porque necesito que la función PHP se ejecute con el clic de otro botón que no es el que originalmente utiliza el plugin para funcionar, pero que haga lo mismo.

El código JS (tiene algunos comentarios para aclarar ciertos puntos):

```
// Sólo que se ejecute cuando se este en esta página. 
if(location.href === "https://www.leogratis.com/venderlibro/"){

  // Este es el botón que desencadena el evento. 
  const agregarLibro      = document.querySelector('.wpuf_submit_34');
  const tituloProducto    = document.querySelector('#post_title_34');
  const categoriaProducto = document.querySelector('#lvl0').firstElementChild;

  agregarLibro.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    //e.preventDefault();
    // El botón envía un formulario así que antes de hacer la petición valido que los campos requeridos no estén vacíos. 
    if(
      tituloProducto.value !== '' && 
      categoriaProducto.value !== '-1' && 
      !document.querySelector('.ui-state-default ,.wpuf-image-wrap, .thumbnail')
    ){
      // La petición del archivo que contiene la función. 
      fetch('/wp-content/plugins/complemento-de-modificacion/woo_product.php')
      // Esto es sólo para ver si la petición se hace correctamente y está funcionando.
      .then(response => console.log(response));
    }
  });
}
```

La función PHP que quiero que se ejecute:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
function um_activity_new_woo_product( $post_id ) {
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
  if (
      get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'product' || 
      get_post_status( $post_id ) != 'publish'
  ) return;

  if ( ! UM()->options()->get('activity-new-product') ) return;

  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if( $post->post_modified_gmt != $post->post_date_gmt ) return;

  if ( !isset( $_POST['original_post_status'] ) ) return;
  if ( 
     sanitize_key( $_POST['post_status'] ) == 'publish' && 
     sanitize_key( $_POST['original_post_status'] ) == 'publish' 
  ){
    return;
  }

  $product = new WC_Product( $post_id );
  $user_id = $post->post_author;
  
  um_fetch_user( $user_id );
  $author_name = um_user('display_name');
  $author_profile = um_user_profile_url();

  $post_image = '';
  $post_image_url = UM()->Activity_API()->api()->get_post_image_url( $post_id );
  if ( $post_image_url ) {
    $post_image_alt = basename( $post_image_url );
    $post_image = '<span class="post-image"><img src="' . 
      esc_attr( $post_image_url ) . '" alt="' . 
      esc_attr( $post_image_alt ) . '" title="' . 
      esc_attr( str_replace( "#", '', get_the_title( $post_id ) ) ) . 
      '" class="um-activity-featured-img" /></span>';
  }

  if ( $post->post_excerpt ) {
    $post_excerpt = '<span class="post-excerpt">' . 
      strip_tags(
       apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt )
      ) . '</span>';
  } elseif ( $post->post_content ) {
    $post_excerpt = '<span class="post-excerpt">' .
      wp_trim_words(
        strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content ), 
        $num_words = 25,
        $more = null 
      ) . '</span>';
  } else {
    $post_excerpt = '';
  }

  UM()->Activity_API()->api()->save(
    array(
      'template' => 'new-product',
      'wall_id' => $user_id,
      'author' => $user_id,
      'author_name' => $author_name,
      'author_profile' => $author_profile,
      'post_title' => '<span class="post-title">' . $post->post_title . '</span>',
      'post_url' => get_permalink( $post_id ),
      'post_excerpt' => $post_excerpt,
      'post_image' => $post_image,
      'price' => '<span class="post-price">' . $product->get_price_html() . '</span>',
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'um_activity_new_woo_product', 99999, 1 );
```

Como podrán ver la función PHP necesita varios valores, como son demasiados lo que espero es que pueda tomarlos desde donde sea que vengan, ya que estoy llamando a la función en el mismo entorno donde están los demás archivos del plugin.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Claro.. pero la funcion, como sabe de donde tomarlos? Esa funcion estara pensanda para ser ejecutada en un momento en particular con un entorno de cosas en particular...

Comment: por lo que se ve la función se ejecuta al grabar un post, chequea que sea un  `product`, pareciera que intenta detectar que es llamada cuando es la primera vez que se graba excluyendo autosaves. deduzco que es para crear un registro en un api externo con cada nuevo producto, cual sería el objetivo de llamar a la función desde el frontend?

Comment: @aloMalbarez si efectivamente es un post de tipo `product `. Se ejecuta cada vez que se crea un producto desde el panel de administración en el backend. La necesidad de llamarla desde el frontend, es porque los usuarios que cargan los productos son usuarios que no tienen acceso al panel del backend, por lo que lo hacen desde un formulario que genera otro plugin y se muestra en una página.

Comment: @gbianchi exacto y es eso exactamente lo que quiero conseguir, replicar ese escenario, pero en el momento que se haga clic en el botón del formulario del frontend. Intenté pasar algunas variables con fetch pero sin éxito.